# Who were Hillel's greatest students and what were they known for?

Tags: rabbis, tannaim, hillel

In [Succah 28a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.28a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the Gemara tells us that Hillel the Elder had 80 students of whom Yochanan ben Zakai was the "least" and Yonason ben Uziel was the greatest.  There, it says of Yonason ben Uziel that his mind was so intense birds flying over his head as he studied would be singed.  Who were Hillel's other great students and what do we know of them?  Do we know the names of Shammai's students?

Comment: Off-topic as Jews not Judaism?

Comment: Possibly Hillel's son Shimon?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9C_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99) lists the following as students of Hillel and Shamai.

Hillel:

רבן גמליאל

רבן שמעון בן גמליאל

רבי יהושע

רבי עקיבא ותלמידיו

Also Rabbi Yochanan ben Zakai and Yonasan ben Uziel that you mentioned.

Shamai:

רבי אליעזר בן הורקנוס

רבי יונתן בן הרכינס

רבי יוחנן בן החורנית

רבי יוסי בן דורמסקית

בבא בן בוטא

רבי גרשון בן יצחק

Comment: AFAIK none of the four listed as students of Hillel were actual students of Hillel; they were followers (successors) of Hillel's academy (or The Hillel :)

Comment: The same is true of all of the alleged students of Shammai except בבא בן בוטא. I've never heard of רבי גרשון בן יצחק and I can't find any information about him online or in any [books](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43956&st=&pgnum=353). I would hazard to say that he doesn't exist and Wikipedia is wrong